# Nginx IP filter with Docker not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have nginx running in a docker container and want to only allow certain IP addresses, but whenever I try to connect, I get an error because the client IP isn't correct.

> nginx_1  | 2018/06/09 08:01:56 [error] 6#6: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: 172.18.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"

It's using the docker client IP instead of the actual host IP.  How can I have it properly forward the true client IP?

Docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./config/nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
           - "80:80"
```

Comment: What's your nginx rule config?